# Black water from kitchen sink cold water line

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens, faucet, mold

Today I noticed my kitchen sink was leaking underneath in the cabinet. I went to take a look and it looked as if it was coming from somewhere inside the faucet. I disconnected the lines and removed the faucet so I could take a better look inside to see if it needed replaced, and when removing the cold water line, I noticed some black water dripped out. I took some q-tips to see if it was coming from the faucet line, the connector, or the house line, and as far as I can tell with the q-tip, it seems to be darkest in the connector and the faucet line, but there is definitely some inside the house line. I figured this could be mold from the connector or faucet that dripped down into the house line, but now I am worried that it has spread deeper down

A couple things: I noticed no water discoloration before this little project. No other faucets have discolored water either, though I havent checked any lines underneath except one or two months back.

The setup of the sink:

Two house lines; one hot and one cold. The cold water line has a connector and then the blue water "pipe" (Im going to call it pipe for lack of a better word, aka I forget what it is called) that comes from the faucet. Dido for the hot water line. The hot water line has an additional "pipe" that goes into the dishwasher. The faucet has a third line, which Im assuming mixes the two lines, that also has the weight attached to pull the faucet hose back in (it is one of the ones that you can pull down). No black water was found anywhere here.

Is there any way to:

1. See how far back the black goes
2. Clean the lines that need it
3. Clean the entire water line

Or should I just call a plumber, and what are the estimated (it can be a very rough estimate) costs with doing so for this type of work

Comment: Could be a rubber seal that's degrading in the connector.

Comment: @brhans Interesting I didnt think of that. Its completely liquid, like its apart of the water now. How can I check to make sure that it is/isnt the rubber seal?

Comment: Any galvanized pipe in your house?